# Loading csv files on Java web application start

Tags: java, csv, servlets

I am writing a java web application using Servlets. It contains two buttons and each one imports some data from some csv files. When a button is pressed the csv files are loaded in again.

Is there any way to load the csv files when the page is iniated? So I will Objectify the csv files to use them later instead of loading them all the time.

Each button is a servlet and it contains this code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String code=req.getParameter("code");
        String name= req.getParameter("name");

        CSVReader reader=new CSVReader();
        ArrayList<Person> people=reader.readPeople(); // reading from csv files
        reader.readParents();
        reader.readKids();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class OnStart implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        //Things for the application to do when it starts
    }

}
```

and in the web.xml file

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>OnStart</listener-class>
</listener>
```